# Extracting media properties in Java or Installing MediaInfo into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, video, mediainfo

In the program I am working on in eclipse. I am required to extract media properties from video files, such as bit rate, codecs, containers etc. I have researched this and have found the MediaInfo JNI however I do not know how to add this to eclipse and when I go to the website provided I cannot seem to download the .jar. Since I am new adding any sort of external plugin's or JNI to eclipse I am clueless.

The main program is, I cannot download the mediaInfo .jar which is found here - 
https://code.google.com/p/subs4me/source/browse/trunk/Subs4me/src/net/sourceforge/filebot/mediainfo/?r=93

If this is a dead end, then is there any other solution to extracting this kind of information in java using eclipse?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can check how filebot does this here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/filebot/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/source/net/sourceforge/filebot/mediainfo/

You just need JNA and the mediainfo native lib.

Comment: Okay So I managed to import the mediainfo java files into ecllipse and added the jna and platform JAR files to the build path. However when i try the code I get an exception. I dont quite understand what it means..

Comment: Here is the error message:  Exception in thread "main" net.sourceforge.filebot.mediainfo.MediaInfoException: Unable to load 64-bit native library 'mediainfo'
 at net.sourceforge.filebot.mediainfo.MediaInfo.<init>(MediaInfo.java:45)
 at main.main(main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'mediainfo': The specified module could not be found.